# I keep being told the remote package repository is outdated

Tags: packages

Every time I try to synchronize my packages, I'm told the remote package repository is outdated. I've tried this with three remote repositories, and always get the same message. Anybody have any idea what's wrong?

Error message below:

> MiKTeX Problem Report Message: The remote package repository is
>   outdated. You have to choose another repository.
>
> Data:
>   url="http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/"
>   Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\RestRemoteService.cpp Line:
>   275 MiKTeX: 2.9 OS: Windows 7

Comment: Same problem here, I tried about 10 repositories. The problem started after updating MikTex produced an error.

Comment: I'd check this myself, but not on Windows today. Faint possibility: Since Daylight Savings Time just changed in most of the USA, maybe the US repositories have a time problem? Does the error happen if you try a repository elsewhere?

Comment: Reported on sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2544/ looks to be international

Comment: Same problem with ftp.heanet.ie (MikTeX 2.9, 64-bit, Windows 10).

Comment: Me and many of my acquaintances and colleagues experience this issue. No solution, except for reinstalling, seems to work

Answer (score 10):

It seems to be a bug on the timestamping or authentication token of the repository in the Windows registry. I have found that removing the full HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\MPM registry key and retrying will fix it.

Comment: Can you really be confident deleting registry keys won't cause other problems?

Comment: The keys are re-created by the MikTeX tools if they are missing.

Comment: I simply waited a day and now the problem is gone.

Comment: It did the same for me once but I recall it came back after installing a new package. I guess the logic on the timestamp is screwed up, adn yes maybe it is affected by the DTS. Anyway IMHO there should be an option to override the outdated repo detection in the GUI.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Wiping the "AuthTokenNotValidAfter" value is actually enough. `reg delete HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\MPM /f /v AuthTokenNotValidAfter`

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Doesn't work at all

Comment: There is no folder HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\MiKTeX.org on my Windows 7

Comment: For me it works but with different path `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\MPM`.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on Windows 10 solved likes this:

1. Remove all MikTex entries from the **registry**.
2. Delete the **MikTeX 2.9** folder from c:\Program Files.
3. Delete the **MikTeX 2.9** folder from c:\users...\AppData\Roaming
   folder.
4. Run the installer and chose **not** to automatically download missing packages.

The last step means that TexWorks will stop at every missing package. Then you close TexWorks, open MikTeX Package Manager, add the package, close the Package Manager, start TexWorks and try again.

Maybe the problem began when I tried to update the installation as suggested on the download web page. Anyway, I have not tried to update my installation and it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was a bug that has been fixed. I've been able to update everything today. Thanks to whoever fixed this bug!

https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2544/

Comment: MiKTeX bugs are reported at GitHub now. This issue is located at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/27. It's actually closed, but not solved!

Comment: I still have this problem with the current release, months on.  How can this be allowed to stand considering how many rely on it?

Comment: Closed??? Are you kidding?

Comment: The key comment is this: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/27#issuecomment-340411617
> **I am afraid that all repositories are currently out-of-date because the last CTAN upload was unsuccessful.**